# Why does this particular exclusionary regex of mine fail?

Tags: regex

The following exclusionary regex should match (throw error on) only the chars in the brackets  < > =
However, it also will throw on a space at the end of a string. Why?

```
/^((?![<>=]).)*$/
```

Comment: Your regex seems very similar, if not identical, to `/^([^<>=])*$/`.

Comment: Your regex [seems to work perfectly well](http://www.rubular.com/r/CIk3weHZDl) to only match strings that don't contain any of those characters. I presume this is not what you want, or the language / tool you're using doesn't support look-around. Can you provide sample strings of what should and shouldn't match and what you want the output to be for each, along with the language / tool you're using?

Comment: What's the implementation? PHP, grep, Perl, awk, python, etc?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Could you perhaps provide some expected output/actual output to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Yes, it is exclusionary, so my meaning was a little inverse in this case; in other words, the intention is to only match strings that do not contain the listed chars, that is indeed the intended behavior. But it does NOT match a string without the listed chars if it also has a space at the end...which seems to makes no sense.

Comment: it matches strings with spaces for me.  can we see the code you're invoking this from? and the sample input you're using and the output?

Comment: I can't show the code because it is a commercial form service...I am putting my regex into a form builder. I appreciate the responses, but it seems nothing is really wrong with the regex. Possibly a glitch in the system somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a complete string, you don't need the look around. The problem is the look around needs a set number of characters in order to work (depending on the implementation meaning no wildcards usually).

If you're checking a whole string, you can use this:

```
/^[^<>=]+$/
```

If you're trying to make sure that doesn't occur at the beginning of the string, then you can use

```
/^[^<>=]/
```

End of the string

```
/[^<>=]$/
```

Beginning or End (not worrying about the middle) you should be able to use this.

```
/(^[^<>=]|[^<>=]$)/
```

If we test these in PHP using the following code:

```
<?php

$phrases = array('dog','cat=dog','<a href=','bird=');

$patterns = array('/^[^<>=]+$/','/^[^<>=]/','/[^<>=]$/','/(^[^<>=].*[^<>=]$)/');

foreach($phrases as $phrase){

    foreach($patterns as $pattern){
        if(preg_match($pattern,$phrase)){
       echo '`'.$pattern."` matches `".$phrase."`\n";   
    } else {
       echo '`'.$pattern."` doesn't match `".$phrase."`\n";         
        }
    }


}


?>
```

We get the following output

`/^[^<>=]+$/` matches `dog`

`/^[^<>=]/` matches `dog`

`/[^<>=]$/` matches `dog`

`/(^[^<>=].*[^<>=]$)/` matches `dog`

`/^[^<>=]+$/` doesn't match `cat=dog`

`/^[^<>=]/` matches `cat=dog`

`/[^<>=]$/` matches `cat=dog`

`/(^[^<>=].*[^<>=]$)/` matches `cat=dog`

`/^[^<>=]+$/` doesn't match `<a href=`

`/^[^<>=]/` doesn't match `<a href=`

`/[^<>=]$/` doesn't match `<a href=`

`/(^[^<>=].*[^<>=]$)/` doesn't match `<a href=`

`/^[^<>=]+$/` doesn't match `bird=`

`/^[^<>=]/` matches `bird=`

`/[^<>=]$/` doesn't match `bird=`

`/(^[^<>=].*[^<>=]$)/` doesn't match `bird=`